# aws config with one domain but two instances to read from possible?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, replication

This just came into my mind and I wonder if the below is possible?

I have a domain `www.example.com`
but the client is all across Canada, would it be a good idea to have a server(including db) in both `Oregon` and `Canada(central)` with db replication
then would using `route53` work to check which geo location is accessing `www.et.com`, if closer to east coast then goes to Canada(central) if closer to west then goes to Oregon
or there's a better way for this?

Thanks in advance for any advices

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network - since you're on AWS, look into CloudFront.

Comment: Route 53 geo load balancing could work for you. You'd have to have full stacks in each region, which could mean databases synchronized between regions - AWS doesn't do that for you though. It's possible to have a web server in one region using a database server in another region but latency might make it pretty slow, hence the need for replication. It really depends what your application is, if it has a database or shared files. We'd need much more information to help - please edit your question and reply if you want more thoughts.

Comment: @Tim There's https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cross-region-read-replicas-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql/ if a read replica in the other region is sufficient. Writes would still have to go to one place, but for a read-heavy site it'd be perfect.

Comment: @ceejayoz yep, we'd need more information about the solution to give more useful advice.